# Cycle Nodes problem. Have no idea where to put ColorRamp

Tags: node-editor

I have no idea where to put a Coloramp node...it is really confusing.

I was texturing an object that i made, but as you can see, it's not going as planned...i scaled my diffuse in the UV map editor, and put in a Texture Coordinate node, and attached the the bump, the specular map to the mix shader, and used a mapping node for the normal maps. However as you can see, the diffuse..isnt quite working well, since there is a colorRamp missing...i am so confused about where it should be.

Here I have a specular map:
[image: Here i have a specular map]

And here I don't have a spec map:
[image: Here i don't have a spec map]

Comment: Could you be more clear?  Are you following a tutorial? Why you need a ColorRamp node? What is each image showing? (you are connecting an image texture directly into the Normal socket of your diffuse shader: are you sure of that?)

Comment: Emmm sry...i added the desc of the images in my post(like in "Enter desc here" after an image upload. I'm trying this one by myself after watching a lot of tutorials. In the first one i have a specular map connected to the Fac of the mix shader and in the second i didn't....Yes! I'm really dumb, xD
1. The specular map that i had was way too powerful(went back to ShaderMap3 and inverted the value)
2. You made me realizer that i should have put the output from the bump to the diffuse
3. I didn't needed of a ColorRamp, the specular map was at fault.

Comment: I feel amazing after finding my mistakes with your help...thank you very much...

Comment: Glat it helped! The "description" of an image I think it's just the lines that appears instead of images when they, for whatever reason, go down.

Answer (score 1):

1. The specular map that i had was way too powerful(went back to ShaderMap3 and inverted the value)
2. @Carlo made me realize that i should have put the output from the bump to the diffuse
3. I didn't needed of a ColorRamp, the specular map was at fault.

Thanks @Carlo